# Oracle sqlplus 12c error with queries

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

```
Airport(Airport, AName, CheckIN, Resvtns, FlightInfo)
Route(RouteNo, RDescription)
Fares(FareType, Fdescription, Conditions)
Tariff(RouteNo , FareType, Price)
Aircraft(AircraftType, ADescription, NoSeats)
Flight(FlightNo, FromAirport, ToAirport, DepTime, ArrTime, Service, AircraftType, RouteNo)
Passenger(Pid, Name, Address, TelNo)
Ticket(TicketNo, TicketDate, PID)
Itinerary(TicketNo, FlightNo, LegNo, FlightDate, FareType)
```

Hi, can someone help me fix this query? The error is written below.

List the names of the passengers with at least two tickets which cost over £180 each.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Passenger 
WHERE Pid IN (SELECT p FROM (SELECT Pid AS p,count(*) AS c FROM Ticket
GROUP BY PID HAVING count(*) >1) AS tic);
```

error: Missing right parenthesis Line 4

Comment: @Graciano It shows for ‘12/8/2004’ . I'm pretty sure that its valid.

Comment: error: Missing right parenthesis Line 4 - where's line 4?

Comment: I fixed the code layout  @Graciano

Comment: I fixed that, it says missing expression.

Comment: please update the code of query #2. query #1 : FlightDate between to_date('10/08/2004', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
      AND to_date('12/08/2004', 'MM/DD/YYYY')

Comment: @Graciano can you help me code the final one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should simply be

```
SELECT name
FROM   passenger
WHERE  pid IN (SELECT pid
               FROM  Ticket
               GROUP  BY pid
               HAVING Count(*) > 1);
```